# run python in sub folder created after "startproject" command

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I'm learning scrapy from a udemy tutorial. 
I've installed Scrapy to the following path:

> c:\Users\User\Anaconda3\Scripts

afterwards I enter in the "startproject" command which creates the project "quotes spider" in a new folder with this path:

> c:\Users\User\Anaconda3\Scripts\quotes_spider

in the tutorial, the instructor changes his directory to that subfolder and is able to call scrapy from that subfolder.

When I try to do that i get the error:

> 'scrapy' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

How am I able to call scrapy from this subfolder??

Comment: Consider creating your project in a different folder than Anaconda.

Answer (score 0):

You will either need to add the path to where scrapy is located to your `Path` Environment Variable (if you're on Windows) or you could run it from your `c:\Users\User\Anaconda3\Scripts` and run the `scrapy` command with relative paths to your `quotes_spider` subfolder.

Comment: if i run scrapy from  c:\Users\User\Anaconda3\Scripts......how do I "run the scrapy command with relative paths to your quotes_spider subfolder"

Comment: Your best option would be to have your `Path` environment variable point to the scrapy directory. What OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Windows 8

Comment: the first recommendation worked...now I think your 2nd one is better long term

Comment: Ah well I think adding the directory to your `Path` is the better solution, it should have been added there anyway but it depends on how you installed scrapy of course. Have fun with the rest of your course!